# preg_match_all giving unknown results

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks as such:

```
"first: [[1394,97],[13944,97]],
second: [[1394,11400],[13944,7898]]"
```

I am trying to use php preg_match_all to simply give me (removing 'first','second')

```
[1394,97],[13944,97],[1394,11400],[13944,7898]
```

So that I can then create arrays using that.

When I use the regex:

```
$reg = "/(\[?(?:\[(\d{1,}),(\d{1,})\]))/";
preg_match_all($reg, $input_string, $matches);
```

I don't understand the output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '[[1394,97]' (length=10)
      1 => string '[13944,97]' (length=10)
      2 => string '[[1394,11400]' (length=13)
      3 => string '[13944,7898]' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '[[1394,97]' (length=10)
      1 => string '[13944,97]' (length=10)
      2 => string '[[1394,11400]' (length=13)
      3 => string '[13944,7898]' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1394' (length=4)
      1 => string '13944' (length=5)
      2 => string '1394' (length=4)
      3 => string '13944' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '97' (length=2)
      1 => string '97' (length=2)
      2 => string '11400' (length=5)
      3 => string '7898' (length=4)
```

How can I modify to just return the first array, which is what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of all the capturing parenthesis `()` like

```
$reg = "/\[\d{1,},\d{1,}\]/";
preg_match_all($reg, $input_string, $matches);
```

will give you an output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1394,97] 
                       [1] => [13944,97] 
                       [2] => [1394,11400] 
                       [3] => [13944,7898] ) )
```